# Mdns packets not received by avahi

Tags: c, embedded, multicast, mdns

I'm porting mdns into my embedded device(in C), it's not using socket but some raw packet tx.

And want to test it with avahi, so I run a virtualbox ubuntu, and build avahi so I can add debug message.

The device and ubuntu are on same local network, and able to ping each others.

The problem is avahi seems not receiving packets from device, I add messages just after avahi recvmsg(), so it's not even about if packet content is legit.

I can see my device sending mdns packets(224.0.0.251:5353), both on ubuntu tcpdump, and the host win10 wireshark (and those packets looks fine, at least wireshark shows no error columns).

On the other hand, avahi actually receives other mdns packets from same local network.

What's the potential problem of this?

Comment: Did you verify that the destination MAC address matches the expected multicast address  i.e. `01:00:5E:00:00:FB`?

Comment: Yes, the dest mac is exactly the same as other mdns packets.

Comment: Is `avahi-daemon` configured to use the network interface which is used to communicate to the virtual machine?

Comment: I'm not doing particular configure about avahi-daemon, but just as I said, it can receive mdns packets normally from others on same local network.  By the way, should my device join multicast group or something? although tcpdump do see that packets without my joining.

Comment: I don't think you need to join the group when you are connected via a switch. How is the network configured in the virtual machine? I asked about the network interface because some of the network options implies having a new interface and if the daemon is not configured to listen to it, it doesn't matter that your OS gets the packet(as tcpdump showed)

Comment: avahi and my device are on the same LAN (192.168.5.x/24), and there are other random mdns senders too, and both avahi and my device can see those sender's packets.  And there's only 2 interfaces on ubuntu, enp0s3 and lo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found the problem.

Because I have to build packets from raw, and I made mistakes when calculating IP header checksum, the value is incorrect.
After fixing this bug, avahi socket can receive those packets.

Because wireshark default disable IP header checksum validation, so it shows no error at first glance.
And for some reason, tcpdump will also accept such packets.